# How do I access Rainbow Falls: Base in Terra's story?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-birth-by-sleep

I have all but 2 treasures in Neverland and everything I've read suggests they are in the "Rainbow Falls: Base" area but I can't get there. Every time I try it says something about "There's nothing interesting over here." This is a file I've cleared the game with and these are the only 2 chests left. Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Rainbow Falls: Base cannot be accessed from the top, and only from around the side. You can get to it by loading into Peter's Hideout, and going to Mermaid Lagoon and following the walkway around to the right. From there, go to the other side of the Seacoast, and you'll end up at Rainbow Falls: Base.

Now I shall chronicle your adventure in advance, using pictures:

[image: Mermaid Lagoon]
[image: Seacoast]
[image: Chest 1]
[image: Fake Chest]
[image: Chest 2]